# Как заполнить ComboBox данными из таблицы DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, combobox

Здравствуйте всем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заполнить ComboBox данными из таблицы DataGrid.

У меня есть два окна. В одном окне у меня есть DataGrid (имя его будет ReaderDataGrid). Это таблица содержит в себе записи о читателях. Теперь мне нужно в другом окне расположить ComboBox (имя его будет OrderComboBox). Этот ComboBox мне нужно заполнить не рандомными значениями, а теми значениями, которые есть в DataGrid (ReaderDataGrid).

В своём проекте я **НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЮ** паттерн MVVM, поскольку данный паттерн для меня слишком сложный в понимании его концепции, хотя не исключаю, что через него мне будет намного проще сделать то, что хочу. Для работы с БД я использую EF.

**P.S. Немного дополнил свой пост.**

Часть кода первого окна:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
        {
            ReaderDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Readers.ToList();
            OrderDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Orders.ToList();
            CatalogDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Catalogs.ToList();
            BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Books.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Часть кода второго окна (не обращайте внимание на название CatalogWindow, я там провожу эксперименты):

```
public partial class CatalogWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainWindow _window;
    private readonly bool _isAddMode; // Булевское поле для проверки режима операции над записью 

    public CatalogWindow(MainWindow window, bool isAddMode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _window = window;
        _isAddMode = isAddMode;
        if (!_isAddMode)
        {
            AddUpdateButton.Content = "Редактировать";
        }

        using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
        {
            ReaderComboBox.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Readers.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Оба окна у меня не диалоговые, хотя второе окно открываю через метод ShowDialog() в MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void CreateCatalogButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CatalogWindow window = new CatalogWindow(this, true);

    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

В конструкторе окна CatalogWindow я добавил это:

```
using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
{
    ReaderComboBox.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Readers.ToList();
}
```

Вот теперь вопрос: как мне преобразовать эту коллекцию в объекты класса Reader? Вернее даже не объекты класса Reader, а нужно сделать так, чтобы в ComboBox выводились для объекта Reader свойство Name (ФИО читателя), а через свойство Id класса Reader я мог уже при операции добавления заносить значения этого Id класса Reader в нужный мне объект другого класса. Немного запутанно написал, но суть в том, что нужно сделать аналогично, как если бы я приложение делал не через WPF, а в Windows Forms. Потому что сейчас вот так происходит, и я не понимаю, как сделать явное преобразование из-за недопонимания (или незнания) иерархии наследуемых классов или мб из-за чего-то другого, что мешает мне сделать это без проблем.
[image: Мой ComboBox с добавленными значениями из ReaderDataGrid]

Comment: второе окно диалоговое?

Comment: если в `DataGrid` попадают значения из таблицы то можно и `ComboBox` заполнить аналогичным образом. Если нет, то можно добавить к окну дополнительный конструктор и передавать данные через него.

Comment: Даже не знаю, что сказать. Я пост свой обновил, прочитайте его концовку, пожалуйста.

Comment: к сожалению, я не могу давать советы по EF так его не использую и вообще с БД имею только поверхностное знакомство. Преобразовывать вы можете явно через `Select` или возможно вам будет достаточно правильно указать `DisplayMemberPath` для `ComboBox`

Comment: попробуйте для `ComboBox` установить `DisplayMemberPath = "Name"`

Comment: Вроде как получилось. Вот такие строчки добавил:
    `ReaderComboBox.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Readers.ToList();`
    `ReaderComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";`
    `ReaderComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Id";`

А вы не знаете, как будет выглядеть эти свойства у ComboBox в XAML разметке? Через код получилось сделать, а вот в XAML разметке через Binding не совсем понимаю, как это можно сделать.